# Difficulty retrieving a value in PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP.  I'm not able to retrieve the value `loopcount`.

Here's the code I've written:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Order</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//This function calculates the total bill by multiplying the price by quantity //selected
    function order()
    {

              var x,y,i,j,p=0;

        j=parseInt(document.getElementById('loopcount').value);

              document.write(j);
        for (i=0;i<=j;i++)
        {
            if(document.getElementById('itemCode[i]').checked==true){
                x=parseFloat( document.getElementById('quantity[i]').value);
                document.write(x);
                y=parseFloat( document.getElementById('price[i]').value);
                document.write(y);
        p+=x*y;
        }
        }
    var conf=confirm("The total amount is:"+ p);

              if(conf==true){
                  header("Location:userHome.php");
              }
              else{
                  header("Location:orderveggies.php");
              }

        }


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

//the database has a table veggies.which contains the item code(primary key),vegetable name
//price/kilo and quantity in stock.The code bvelow displays data as checkboxes.select the 
//items required and click on order .which gives the total bill ask if it can continue or
//change order
        <form name="myForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" onsubmit="order()">
        <table align="center" border="0">
            <tr>

                <th>item Code</th>
                <th>Vegetable</th>
                <th>Price/KG</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>


             <?php

             $db=  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ourveggies')
                            or die("Error!Could not connect to the database");
                    $query="select itemCode,itemName,price from veggies";
                    $result=mysqli_query($db,$query)
                            or die("Error in query".mysqli_error($db));
                    $count=mysqli_affected_rows($db);
                    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="itemCode[]" value="<?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?>"/><?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['itemName']; ?></td>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"/><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
                        <td><select name="quantity[]">
                                <option value="0.00">--Quantity--</option>
                                <option value="0.100">100 gm</option>
                                <option value="0.250">250 gm</option>
                                <option value="0.500">500 gm</option>
                            </select></td>
                        </tr>

                  <?php  }?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="loopcount" value="<?php echo $count; ?>"/>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="order" value="order" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what a mess. First you need to learn the distinction between javascript and php

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) is for update/delete queries, to tell you how many rows were deleted or updated (e.g. 'affected'). You're running a select query, so there are no affected rows - selects do not change data.

To get the number of rows retrieved by a select, you want [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) instead.

Comment: Its not working.Is something wrong with the javascript,For some reason it isnt retrieving the loopcount value.

Comment: for one, you're doing `getElementById()`, but have no element with an id of `loopcount`... names are not ids.

Comment: Hey now the loopcount is getting retrieved but not the arrays-itemCode[],price[].

Comment: take a good long HARD look at `document.getElementById('price[i]').value);` and see if you can figure out why that's wrong.

Comment: how is javascript supposed to know that `[i]` in that string is actually an array reference, and the i is a variable? try `...getElementById('price[' + i + ']').value`. if js worked in the way you seemed to expect in that code, the i in price would've also been translatd to the value of the i variable, and no strings in js would've been safe from random variable-looking things in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var conf=confirm("The total amount is:"+ p);

    if(conf==true){
        header("Location:userHome.php");
    }
    else{
        header("Location:orderveggies.php");
    }

}
```

you are aware that you try to use a serversided php method in browsersided javascript?